# no implicit conversion of String into Integer by geting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

i'm tring to get the data from the api in shape
but i receive the error:

**no implicit conversion of String into Integer**

```
require 'rest-client'

class Cmc
     url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/'
     response = RestClient.get(url)
     @jsonData = JSON.parse(response)  
end

coins = Cmc.new

coins.listings.each do |data|
  puts "nrcoin: #{data['id']} | 
        namecoin: #{data['name']} | 
        symbolcoin: #{data['symbol']} | 
        slugcoin: #{data['website_slug']}"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coding is not proper. I modified your code. Please run this. I hope it should work.

```
# You have to install bellow gems to your local machine
# gem install rest-client
# gem install json

require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

class Cmc
  def self.listings
     url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/'
     response = RestClient.get(url)
     JSON.parse(response)
   end
end

coins = Cmc.listings

coins["data"].each do |data|
  puts "nrcoin: #{data['id']} |
        namecoin: #{data['name']} |
        symbolcoin: #{data['symbol']} |
        slugcoin: #{data['website_slug']}"
end
```

Comment: it works :) thank you. i didnt know this about "data". Cool for next time :)